# Can I make ViewController inactive in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I made a ViewController for my app that turned out to be more work than I can deal with right now. However I want to save the work for a future version.

My problem is that right now I'm getting the warning:

`".../Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: “Calendar“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]."`

Is there any way to make this warning go away without outright deleting the View Controller? I looked for an attribute to simply deactivate / disable the ViewController, but it doesn't seem possible. Can I then trick Xcode into thinking that it's accessible even when it's not?

Answer (score 0):

Adding any text value for "Storyboard ID" in the view controller -> Identity inspector -> Identity seemed to do the trick.

(thanks to whoever suggested that in a now deleted comment; it didn't work at first for some reason, but now it does)